# Need Help with Some Advanced Integration By Parts Methods

Tags: analysis, factorial, gamma-function

Note: I am asking this question for someone to check my work for me. The problem started out with me finding z! which is equal to the $\mathbf P \mathbf i$ $\mathbf f \mathbf u \mathbf n \mathbf c \mathbf t \mathbf i \mathbf o \mathbf n$ $(z)$ 
 $\mathbf P \mathbf i$ $\mathbf f \mathbf u \mathbf n \mathbf c \mathbf t \mathbf i \mathbf o \mathbf n$ $(z)$ = $\int_0^\infty$ $t^z$ $e^{-t}$ $dt$, Note: I got this online from the Wikipedia on Factorials explaining the extension of factorial to non-integer values of argument. I tried answering it to see if I can do it. Can somebody check my answer and give me a detailed way of actually showing the integration by parts way correctly if I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbf P \mathbf i$ $\mathbf f \mathbf u \mathbf n \mathbf c \mathbf t \mathbf i \mathbf o \mathbf n$ $(z)$ = $\int_0^\infty$ $t^z$$e^-t$ $dt$ 
By using integration by parts, I got 
$-t^z$ $e^{-t}$ $\mid_0^\infty$ $+$ $z$ $\int_0^\infty$ $e^{-t}$ $t^{z-1}$ $dt$ 
$= z$ $\int_0^\infty$ $e^{-t}$ $t^{z-1}$ $dt$ 
 =$\mathbf P \mathbf i$ $\mathbf f \mathbf u \mathbf n \mathbf c \mathbf t \mathbf i \mathbf o \mathbf n$ $(z-1)$ 
Note: I let $u= t^z$ and $v= e^{-t}$
Hence the left-hand side cancelling in the first row because it goes to $0$ once I computed it. 
 The last step someone told me that my second line would be equal to $\mathbf P \mathbf i$ $\mathbf f \mathbf u \mathbf n \mathbf c \mathbf t \mathbf i \mathbf o \mathbf n$ $(z-1)$. That part was not not clear to me

Comment: Denoting the function as $\pi(z)=\int_0^\infty t^ze^{-t}dt,\pi(z-1)$ can be easily generated by substituting $z$ by $z-1$; i.e. $\pi(z-1)=\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt$. Note that you missed a $z$ before $\pi(z-1)$.